# How to access scope of transcluded elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive element. Within it I have a form that I want to set some of the directive's scope properties. Like so:

```
 <trans-dir>
    <form role='form' class='form-inline'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        Select Value:
        <label>
          <input type='radio' ng-model='data' value='Val1'>Val1
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type='radio' ng-model='data' value='Val2'>Val2
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </trans-dir>
```

I'm baffled by how the scopes work (even though I've read a bunch about it):

- Parent controller scope: 03
- Directive controller: 04
- Directive postLink: 04
- Directive transcludeFn: 08
- FORM scope: 05  *<== Huh?*

So, I want the form to set the directive controller's scope. If it were the same scope, that would be fine. If it were the transcluded scope (08) I could then access it. No problem. But it's yet another scope - 05.  I can traverse to it using trasnscludedScope.$$prevSibling, but I don't really know what's going on and I don't know if that is legit and deterministic.

More detailed code at: http://plnkr.co/edit/z70R6W?p=preview

So my questions:

1. How do I access the FORM scope?
2. What's going on with these scopes? Why is my form scope different from my transcluded scope?
3. Bonus: Where are scopes 6 & 7??  (In my real project I have tons of scopes I don't know the source of, and batarang always says they have no model, which can't always be true.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ng-transclude`, you don't need to call `transcludeFn` manually. When you call it manually, you're creating the #8 scope. It is called automatically by `ng-transclude` to create #5. So, the form scope *is* the transcluded scope, just not the one that you're creating manually (that's why it doesn't have the $watch set on it). I'm not sure if there's a way to access the auto-generated transclude scope created by `ng-transclude`. You could, however, not use `ng-transclude`, and instead make your manual call to `transcludeFn` (like you are already doing) and manually append the cloned element to your DOM.

Comment: Ah - I thought the transclude function was a way they gave you to access the scope (which wasn't working).  I removed it, so now I lost a scope but the directive and form are STILL in different scopes. BUT, I have read that the directive and transclude are expected to be siblings, so now, perhaps, I can feel comfortable using 'prevSibling'. Unless there is a better, more direct way. (Simpler: http://plnkr.co/edit/v0j5by?p=preview)

Comment: That was the ticket - removing the transcludeFn removed the extraneous scope. Then you can dependably use $$prevSibling from the transcluded element to set something in the scope of the parent (actually sibling) element. Working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/XU32X6?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your directives will inherit their parent scope if one isn't declared, so removing that will simplify this.

Also, one of those scope gotchas about angular:

If you set a "plain variable" in a child that inherits scope from a parent, it WON'T propagate back up — it will have its own variable instantiated and updated.

```
$scope.plainString = "derp";
// child will inherit this, but if it gets set in child it will be
// instantiated there as its own variable and won't affect the parent
```

However, if there is a query as part of that, the variable will be changed in the parent.

```
$scope.objToQuery = {
    value: "derp"
};
// child will inherit this, and when it gets changed there
// e.g. ng-model="objToQuery.value"
// it WILL be changed in the parent
```

This object that you "query" must exist in the parent scope.

Check out this modified plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/SftstP7L2OJnfLka8OLd?p=preview

Does this help?

Comment: I need the isolate scope, not for this code, but for my real code. And the object vs. property is a good gotcha, but I don't thinks solves my problem here because the directive is a sibling, not parent, to the transclude (Test that fails: http://plnkr.co/edit/H7JPIE?p=preview) But thanks anyway.